# Google Drive SDK does not return the selfLink field for comments

Tags: google-drive-api

For any comment that I request with the API (even the in-documentation examples), the `selfLink` field is missing:

```
 { 
 "kind": "drive#comment",
 "commentId": "AAAAAF8FAJI",
 "createdDate": "2013-05-08T12:59:49.090Z",
 "modifiedDate": "2013-05-08T12:59:49.090Z",
 "author": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "XXX",
  "picture": {
   "url": "//photo.jpg"
  },
  "isAuthenticatedUser": false
 },
 "htmlContent": "XXXX",
 "deleted": false,
 "status": "open",
 "context": {
  "type": "text/html",
  "value": "Some context"
 },
 "anchor": "kix.5hi345vj8mn5",
 "fileId": "sP98Rdx5lB7nbcNL6XD6msg",
 "fileTitle": "XXXX",
 "replies": [
 ]
}
```

Yet it's documented here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments